# @JsonInclude of jackson not work in Jersey post

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson

I have tried to using Jersey and Jackson to serialized java object to json and post, however, while some field in java object is null, I need to send json without the field.

Java object as below

```
public class ProbeData
{
    private String deviceId;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private Double[] location = null;
    private Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ProbeData() {}

    public ProbeData(String deviceId, Double[] location, Map<String, String> tags)
    {
       this.deviceId = deviceId;
       this.location = location;
       this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Jersey post request as below

```
    baseURL = "http://localhost:9090/";
    clientConfig = new ClientConfig().register(new JacksonFeature());
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
    HttpAuthenticationFeature auth = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("admin", "admin");
    webTarget = client.target(baseURL).register(auth);

    webTarget.path(serviceName).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.entity(probeData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class).getStatus();
```

However, the Json still become

```
 "deviceId" : "1000000002",
 "location" : [
         0,
         0
 ],
 "tags" : {

 },
```

Where I expected

```
"deviceId" : "1000000002",
 "tags" : {

 },
```

Import and mvn dependencies as follows

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is @JsonInclude dones't work while using Jersey webTarget request?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `location` is clearly not null, it is an array of two zeroes.  Why do you expect `NON_NULL` to exclude a non-null property?

Comment: Hi Mark, if I give private Double[] location = null; and ProbeData probeData = new ProbeData("100001", null, new HashMap<String, String>()); The location variable shall be null? or you mean it would be an array of two zeroes even I have assigned null to it? Thanks

Comment: Well you're not giving us complete code that reproduces the problem, so if I had to guess I'd say that you're incorrect, and that location is not null.  If you can post a complete, compilable snippet that demonstrates the problem then maybe we can help.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. I have found that Jackson databind lib would not work on Collections correctly.(Array, Map etc..) It seems that been fixed after v2.5.0. However, the most updated jersey-media-json-jackson lib(v2.16) which I have used is dependency with 2.3.2 only. I have absolutely sure that location array is null and only deviceId String is work with @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL), tags Map instead.